# How do I access inner objects when iterating a nested Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

`result` is a nested object:

```js
var result =
    {
        "firstGroup": {
            "2020": [
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 ver 1"},
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 ver 2"}
            ],
            "2021": [
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 ver 3"},
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 ver 4"}
            ],
            "firstSum": {
                "2020": [
                    {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 sum 1"},
                    {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 sum 2"}
                ],
                "2021": [
                    {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 sum 3"},
                    {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 sum 4"}
                ],
            }
        },

        "secondGroup": {
            "2020": [
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 ver 1"},
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 ver 2"}
            ],
            "2021": [
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 ver 3"},
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 ver 4"}
            ],
            "secondSum": {
                "2020": [
                    {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 sum 1"},
                    {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 sum 2"}
                ],
                "2021": [
                    {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 sum 3"},
                    {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 sum 4"}
                ],
            }
        }
    };
```

I know how to iterate the first level nested objects (`firstGroup` and `secondGroup`), but how do I iterate through the nested objects within each of these?

My Code:

```
var groupName;
  var groupArray;
  var index;

  for (groupName in result) {
      groupArray = result[groupName];
      display(groupName + " has " + groupArray.length + " versions listed");
      for (index = 0; index < groupArray.length; ++index) {
        display("* " + groupArray[index].prod_ver);
      }
  }

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
```

My work: http://jsbin.com/uyagoc/1/edit?js,output

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I want to output the records that are in the years

Comment: Just the ones that look like years? What do you want to do when you get to eg `firstSum` which is a different structure to the keys above it (`2020` and `2021`)

Comment: First, that's not JSON, that's just a Javascript object. I fixed that for you. Second, your question `result` object isn't the same as your jsbin `result` object. The code seems to be written for the jsbin object -- the question object does't have any arrays. We cannot help you if you don't state your problem accurately and consistently. It should be able to run with no errors other than those you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, most of your data there are not arrays, they are nested objects. So it is somewhat easier to use `Object.entries` rather than `for` or `foreach` loops.

You can use `forEach` methods to iterate over them and destructure the data into a useful objects:

```
Object.entries(result).forEach( ([groupName,group]) => {
  const groupArray = Object.entries(group);
  display(groupName + " has " + groupArray.length + " versions listed");
  groupArray.forEach( ([year,items]) => {
      display("* " + year);
      items.forEach( obj => {
          display("** " + obj.prod_ver)
      })
  })
});
```

Where this goes wrong, is that you get to a key `firstSum` which is further nested. I'm not entirely clear what you want to achieve here (let me know and I can update this answer).

Live example:

```js
var result = {
  "firstGroup": {
    "2020": [{
        "prod_ver": "prod 1 ver 1"
      },
      {
        "prod_ver": "prod 1 ver 2"
      }
    ],
    "2021": [{
        "prod_ver": "prod 1 ver 3"
      },
      {
        "prod_ver": "prod 1 ver 4"
      }
    ],
    "firstSum": {
      "2020": [{
          "prod_ver": "prod 1 sum 1"
        },
        {
          "prod_ver": "prod 1 sum 2"
        }
      ],
      "2021": [{
          "prod_ver": "prod 1 sum 3"
        },
        {
          "prod_ver": "prod 1 sum 4"
        }
      ],
    }
  },

  "secondGroup": {
    "2020": [{
        "prod_ver": "prod 2 ver 1"
      },
      {
        "prod_ver": "prod 2 ver 2"
      }
    ],
    "2021": [{
        "prod_ver": "prod 2 ver 3"
      },
      {
        "prod_ver": "prod 2 ver 4"
      }
    ],
    "secondSum": {
      "2020": [{
          "prod_ver": "prod 2 sum 1"
        },
        {
          "prod_ver": "prod 2 sum 2"
        }
      ],
      "2021": [{
          "prod_ver": "prod 2 sum 3"
        },
        {
          "prod_ver": "prod 2 sum 4"
        }
      ],
    }
  }
};

Object.entries(result).forEach( ([groupName,group]) => {
  const groupArray = Object.entries(group);
  display(groupName + " has " + groupArray.length + " versions listed");
  groupArray.forEach( ([year,items]) => {
      display("* " + year);
      items.forEach( obj => {
          display("** " + obj.prod_ver)
      })
  })
});

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna do that too, but see my comment above. His jsbin object does have arrays. He needs to fix his question.

Comment: @Inigo I cant access jsbin - blocked by corporate  - so cant see what is there

Comment: well hopefully you're lucky and solved the right problem! ;)